# replace some string after certain other string with sed

Tags: bash, replace, sed

In my config file I have an asset version like:

```
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    assets_version: 20161021
```

When i plan to make a new release i want to replace current version (in this case 20161021) in a bash script with new version (for example with current date).

i have searched long time for examples of sed use but without success.

My Code:

```
sed -e 's/(::\s+assets_version:)[^=]*$/\1 assets/' app/config/config.yml
```

But console told me: sed: 1: "s/(::\s+assets_version: ...": \1 not defined in the RE

Can anybody help?

Comment: Use `s/\(...\)/\1/` or better the answer of @Nasr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VERSION=20161101
sed -i "s/assets_version.*/asserts_version: ${VERSION}/" app/config/config.yml
```

`-i` to change on the same file

`assets_version.*` matches `assets_version` and any more character on the line then replace them.